# Getting fn.Name is not a function error while invoking a known function on axios response in typescript (reactjs)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios

I have the following response type

```
class ServiceResponse<T> {

    status_code: number
    message: string
    data: T

    wasSuccessful(): boolean {
        return this.status_code == 200
    }
}


class LoginResponse {
    action: string
    user: User
}

class User {
    name: string
    provider: string
    email: string
    email_verified: number
    api_token: string
}
```

After calling post request using `axios` in `reactjs`

```
async function login(email: string, password: string): Promise<LoginResponse> {
    var userResponse: Promise<LoginResponse>
    try {
        const response = await Axios.default.post<ServiceResponse<LoginResponse>>(
            Endpoints.login,
            {
                "email": email,
                "password": password,
                "provider": "email"
            }
        )
        console.log(response.data.wasSuccessful())
        userResponse = Promise.resolve(response.data.data)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        userResponse = Promise.reject(error)
    }

    return userResponse
}
```

**`response.data.wasSuccessful()`** throws the following error, although `function is defined` in the response class.

```
TypeError: response.data.wasSuccessful is not a function
    at _callee$ (LoginService.tsx:37)
    at tryCatch (runtime.js:45)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (runtime.js:274)
    at Generator.prototype.<computed> [as next] (runtime.js:97)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (LoginService.tsx:8)
    at _next (LoginService.tsx:10)
```

PS: May be there is something basic that I am missing, I don't know. I have just started learning reactjs and typescript.

Comment: Are you using an axios transformer or interceptor to transform the response to an instance of your class?

Comment: I don't think so. Do I need to?

Comment: Yup, setting the type doesn't make axios transform it for you - it only tells typescript that this is the type, even if it isn't. There's an example here: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1510

Comment: Cool. I thought it is same as `Retrofit calls` in Android ;) Good catch. Let me try.